# Using IF in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to check (here for an example) if the average earnings of DE workers are higher than IT workers. I tried using

```
SELECT IF(
(SELECT AVG(earnings) FROM workers WHERE country LIKE 'DE') > 
(SELECT AVG(earnings) FROM workers WHERE country LIKE 'IT'),
'True', 'False');
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Is there any way to do this in PostgresSQL (I am using version 14)

| first_name | last_name | country | earnings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Andrea | Pfeiffer | DE | 800 |
| Eufrosina | Marchesi | IT | 2975 |
| Elisa | Sabbatini | IT | 2450 |
| Marco | Grunewald | DE | 3000 |
| Doreen | Kalb | DE | 5000 |
| Isidoro | Bruno | IT | 1100 |
| Lucas | Mueller | DE | 3000 |
| Ausonio | Loggia | IT | 1300 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres knows a Boolean type and Boolean expressions will evaluate to a value of that type. So you could simply `SELECT` the expression.

```
SELECT (SELECT avg(earnings)
               FROM workers
               WHERE country = 'DE')
       > 
       (SELECT avg(earnings)
               FROM workers
               WHERE country = 'IT');
```

Or, if you explicitly need strings, use a `CASE` expression.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN (SELECT avg(earnings)
                      FROM workers
                      WHERE country = 'DE')
              > 
              (SELECT avg(earnings)
                      FROM workers
                      WHERE country = 'IT') THEN
           'True'
         ELSE
           'False'
       END;
```

And you could even use Postgres' `FILTER` to get rid of the sub selects. (That might be a bit faster.)

For a Boolean:

```
SELECT avg(earnings) FILTER (WHERE country = 'DE')
       >
       avg(earnings) FILTER (WHERE country = 'IT')
       FROM workers;
```

For a string:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN avg(earnings) FILTER (WHERE country = 'DE')
              >
              avg(earnings) FILTER (WHERE country = 'IT') THEN
           'True'
         ELSE
           'False'
       END
       FROM workers;
```

Instead of `FILTER` you could also use a `CASE` expression as argument to `avg()` with the same effect.

```
avg(earnings) FILTER (WHERE country = 'DE')
```

would become

```
avg(CASE
      WHEN country = 'DE' THEN
        earnings
    END)
```

(and analog for `'IT'`).
That would also work in many other DBMS, not just Postgres.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think it could be written down so simply. The second expression is exactly what I needed. As I understand it `FILTER` is used only in PostgreSQL so I can't use it in MySQL for example?

Comment: @DominikCzekański: Yes, `FILTER` is a Postgres only thing. At least I didn't encounter it anywhere else yet.

Comment: @DominikCzekański: But in many other DBMS you could use (yet another) `CASE` expression to get something with the same effect of `FILTER`. I edited the answer to include that as well.

Comment: @stickybit looking at the documentation, FILTER doesn't seem to be a Postgres extension (it is a keyword in ANSI-SQL, and there is no NOTE in the aggregate documentation) Maybe Postgres is the only DBMS that actually implemented it?

Comment: @wildplasser: Oh, I didn't know that it was actually ANSI-SQL. Out of interest I did a little research and according to [this](https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter) SQLite also seems to implement it. And there is a third party plugin for MySQL that emulates it. But in general all the other major DBMS don't implement it (yet).

Comment: Filter is standard SQL, but not implemented by all types of databases. https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter